# SQL Error: permission denied for schema public

Tags: sql, popsql

So i went ahead for the 4 Hour SQL tutorial and really followed the video - failed on first task, not sure why - Using PopSQL

Im suspecting the difference in colour of INT and PRIMARY KEY might be indicative, not sure how to fix

Error: permission denied for schema public

```
CREATE TABLE student 
(
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    nama VARCHAR(20),
    major VARCHAR(20)
);
```

and this came out when I tried to run (I'm suspecting its about the difference in colour)

> FAILED
>
> permission denied for schema public LINE 1: ...017bc70-b89b-11ec-ad6c-97c51c55f0a9*/ CREATE TABLE student ( ^

[The code I entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Onb.png)

[problem continue after I removed the comma as suggested, using POPSQL fyi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbwOZ.png)

[image: Tutorial, the code is okay, mine is not]

[image: Tried using one of the answers provided]

Comment: Having a look at the image, there's an extra comma, which's just before the closing parentheses, yields the error you met. eg. just remove that comma.

Comment: removed it , but problem still persist. Result after running it I have added picture

Comment: need to leave the statement **alone** as you already presented as the text in the question : `CREATE TABLE student( student_id ........, major VARCHAR(20));`

Comment: seeing different statements (`create table students...` and `create table yourScheme.student..`), and different errors (`near "GO"` and `denied for schema public`), , it's pretty unclear what the exact question is, please focus on 1 question at a time.

Comment: I was following the answer given, just editing to show the result of those answer. Sorry real newbie here.

Really I was following the Giraffe Academy tutorial and already stuck at 1.26hour which is literally the first task using PopSQL.....so trying to get answer here

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.**
Get the ownership of the schema. See: [GRANT Schema Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Solution 2.**
Create a new schema. You will be the owner of the new schema.

```
CREATE SCHEMA yourScheme;
GO
CREATE TABLE yourScheme.student 
(
   student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   nama VARCHAR(20),
   major VARCHAR(20)
);
```